# How can I deserialize an XML - Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, windows-phone

I'm using this function to deserialise the data of the xml file:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("/XML/ligne1_EUROPE.xml", UriKind.Relative);
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load("XML/ligne1_EUROPE.xml"); 
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Destinataires));
        Destinataires ArretLoad = (Destinataires)serializer.Deserialize(document.CreateReader());
        listBox.ItemsSource = ArretLoad.Collection;
```

He call the Destinataires class:

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class Destinataires
{
    [XmlArray("Destinataires")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Destinataire")]

    [XmlArrayItem("Horraires")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Horraire")]

    public ObservableCollection<XML_Arret> Collection { get; set; }
}
```

And call the XML_Arret class:

```
public class XML_Arret
{
    [XmlElement("Designation")]
    public string Designation { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Carre")]
    public string Carre { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Horraires")]
    public Horraires[] Horaires { get; set; }

    public class Horraires
    {
        [XmlElement("Horraire")]
        public string Horraire { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My XML files is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
  <Destinataires>
    <Destinataire>
      <Designation>Faubourd d'isle</Designation>
      <Carre>images/1.png</Carre>
      <Horraires>
        <Horraire>6h18</Horraire>
        <Horraire>6h28</Horraire>
        <Horraire>6h38</Horraire>
          ...
      </Horraires>
    </Destinataire>
        ...
  </Destinataires
</root>
```

But when I debug my programm, I've this message:
*Une exception de type 'System.InvalidOperationException' s'est produite dans System.Xml.Serialization.ni.dll mais n'a pas été gérée dans le code utilisateur*
at the line: 
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Destinataires));

So, I'm lost, Do you can Help me?

And I'm sorry for my langage, I'm a french person.

Thanks

---

I've change my code for:

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class Destinataires
{
    [XmlArray("Destinataires")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Destinataire")]

    public ObservableCollection<XML_Arret> Collection { get; set; }
}
```

But I've a problem:

I use this function:

```
private void ArretList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var app = App.Current as App;
        app.selectArret = (XML_Arret) listBox.SelectedItem;
        var arret = app.selectArret.Designation;
        MessageBox.Show(arret);
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/BUS_InfoArret.xaml?Arret=" + arret, UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

In my app.xaml.cs I've:

```
 public XML_Arret selectArret { get; set; }
```

And In my BUS_InfoArret:
    XML_Arret arret;
        public BUS_InfoArret()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

```
        var app = App.Current as App;
        arret = app.selectArret;

        Designation.Text = arret.Designation.ToString(); <-- Work

        for (int i = 0; i < arret.Horaires.Length;  ++i) <-- Display Ville_st_quentin.XML_Arret+Horraires
        {
            foreach (var item in arret.Horaires)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: apologies, I hit return accidentally there, please see my answer rather than the comment which makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Horraire and Destinaire are both annotated to have the XML tag "Horraire" which is confusing the serializer, change the Destinaire class to :

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class Destinataires
{
    [XmlArray("Destinataires")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Destinataire")]
    public ObservableCollection<XML_Arret> Collection { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks It Work, but I would like xhen I selecte an Element in my list, for example 'Faubourd d'isle', see her schedule.

Comment: When the XML could be read in correctly all data should be present. So is your question how to display that data? Anyway, when this answer solved your question you should accept it and not extend it with a different problem :)

Comment: I've change my initial answer with MikeW help.